# setting indentity1 and identity2 in compare.linkage

Tags: r, linkage

When I use the R function compare.linkage from `RecordLinkage` I want to setup the `indentity1` and 2 parameters.

the code

```
rpairs=compare.linkage(local,distant,blockfld=FALSE,identity1=ind1,identity2=ind2)
```

> Error in compare.linkage(local, distant, blockfld = FALSE, identity1 =
>   ind1,  :    Length of identity1 does not match number of records!

`ind1` are the numbers of the row of distant that match with the numbers `ind2` of local.

I have 2 dataset ans the numbers of the row in the two dataset that are matching.
But I don't know the syntax of the two parameters.

Comment: So i see in the code that ind1 have to having the same length of local. but what is the form of ind1, Is it with true and false ?

Comment: Si i have understand : i make ind1=6981:6980+223  et ind2=1:6980

Comment: and ind1[ind_rowmatchingin local1]=ind row matching in distant